# Kommasetzung bei "sowohl als auch"

Tags: conjunction, comma

Ich habe einen Satz mit "sowohl ... als auch", bei dem ich mir mit der Kommasetzung nicht sicher bin. Ich habe gelesen, dass bei Wörtern oder Wortgruppen kein Komma gesetzt wird, bei Infinitivgruppen und Teilsätzen jedoch schon. Hier bin ich mir dennoch unsicher:

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen, im Bereich Bildverarbeitung, als auch
>   direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

Comment: _Sowohl_ gehört hier inhaltlich zur Infinitivgruppe. Daher sollte der Satz wohl besser lauten: „Ich kann mir vorstellen, sowohl im Bereich Bildverarbeitung als auch direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.“

Comment: *sowohl als auch* - kein Komma, *Infinitivgruppe mit "zu"* - Komma. Genau  so, wie @Loong schreibt.

Comment: @Loong: Daran habe ich auch gedacht, jedoch verändert das die Bedeutung. Es hieße dann nämlich, dass ich mir vorstellen könnte, beides _gleichzeitig_ zu machen. Die beabsichtigte Bedeutung ist aber, dass ich mir beides vorstellen könnte, aber am Ende natürlich nur eines von beidem eintritt. Vielleicht müsste man den Satz umformulieren in: "Ich könnte mir sowohl vorstellen, im Bereich Bildverarbeitung zu arbeiten, als auch direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen."

Comment: @user1488118 Die Kommasetzung ändert im Deutschen grundsätzlich nie etwas an der Bedeutung (das würde gesprochene Sprache ziemlich schwierig machen), sondern ist entweder richtig oder falsch... Wenn du die Bedeutung ändern möchtest, musst du schon den Satz umstellen

Comment: @tofro Das würde ich so nicht behaupten. Es gibt sicherlich Beispiel, wo ein gesetztes oder weggelassenes Komma die Bedeutung ändert. (Gesprochen wäre das dann über Betonungen und Satzmelodie realisiert.)

Comment: @Tofro, "Wir essen jetzt Opa" (Satzzeichen können Leben retten)

Comment: @tofro Es wurde ja bei dem Vorschlag von Loong auch nicht nur die Kommasetzung verändert, sondern die Wörter "sowohl" und "vorstellen" wurden vertauscht.

Comment: Ich würde kein einziges Komma setzen.

Answer (score 2):

Die Kommasetzung ist im Deutschen etwas, womit viele Mühe haben (auch Muttersprachler).
Oft ist die Kommasetzung intuitiv. Ich versuche mir, den Satz in meinem Kopf aufzusagen und bei jedem Stop (ausser vor *und* und *oder*) ein Komma zu setzen.

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen, im Bereich Bildverarbeitung, als auch direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

Wie loong schon festgestellt hat, ist es schwer, den Satz zu verstehen. Dies liegt an der falschen Kommasetzung. Richtig wäre:

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen im Bereich Bildverarbeitung, als auch direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

Somit behält der Satz seine Bedeutung, ist jedoch deutlich einfacher zu lesen.
In diesem Beispiel kann jedoch auch

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen im Bereich Bildverarbeitung als auch direkt im Bereich der CT-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

richtig sein, da dieses Komma primär ein Stilmittel ist.
Ich empfinde die erste Variante jedoch als intuitiver und darum „richtiger“.

Answer (score -1):

Kommata sätze ich nur bei wirklichen Infinitiverweiterungen

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen, im Bereich Bildverarbeitung **zu arbeiten**, als auch, direkt im Bereich der CV-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

aber nicht vor Deinem elliptischen Nichtmalinfinitiv

> Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen im Bereich Bildverarbeitung, als auch direkt im Bereich der CV-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen zu arbeiten.

oder noch deutlicher nicht in eine zusammenhängende Verortungsphrase

> Ich kann mir sowohl im Bereich Bildverarbeitung als auch direkt im Bereich der CV-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen vorstellen zu arbeiten.

die Du auch bildzeitungsdeutschlicher parzellieren könntest:

> An anderem in der Bildverarbeitung arbeiten?  Oder weiter an CV-Rekonstruktionsalgorithmen?  Mir wäre beides recht!